# Ice vs Insulation in a Cooler

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a **middle grade** cooler that fits in a chest freezer. I transport one or two containers of frozen berries. Along the bottom, top and ends the berries are surrounded by 1 liter ice jugs. The cooler and contents are 0F

I could purchase a **higher grade** cooler with better insulation that would fit in the chest freezer. The better cooler would have less room for ice, but more and possibly better insulation.

Which would keep the berries frozen longer when kept in the car on multi-day trips in summer?

I use a space blanket (and closed cell insulation under it, and around the cooler when possible) to reflect sun. Is this a useful practice?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think? ... This reads like a school exercise. The policy here is not to do students' homework for them.

Comment: I can understand how my inquiry may seem like a school assignment, but it is not. I'm long out of school.

Comment: Deciding which option is better will depend on several factors which would need to be measured - dimensions of the coolers, volume of berries and ice, thermal properties of the containers and blanket. These have to be weighed against the additional cost of the new cooler. This will make it impossible to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Provided that the ice does not melt during the trip, having more of it will not provide any additional benefit. Having space for cold air to circulate is beneficial. Yes the use of a space blanket would be useful.